# How to solve Attempt to invoke virtual method 'com.google.firebase.firestore.CollectionReference error

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to achieve register a user in firestore and at the same time save the user's details into the firestore. I have successfully registered a user, but I'm unable to save the user information as a collection in Firebase I'm getting an error like the one below,

[image]

> **FATAL EXCEPTION: main
> Process: com.example.loginapp, PID: 4826
> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'com.google.firebase.firestore.CollectionReference com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestore.collection(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference**

Register.java

```
package com.example.loginapp;

import static android.content.ContentValues.TAG;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText;
import com.google.firebase.auth.AuthResult;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.DocumentReference;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestore;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class Register extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextInputEditText editTextEmail,editTextPassword;
    EditText nameEditText;
    Button buttonReg;
    ProgressBar progressBar;
    TextView textView;
    FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    FirebaseFirestore fStore;

    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        // Check if user is signed in (non-null) and update UI accordingly.
        FirebaseUser currentUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
        if(currentUser != null){
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);

        editTextEmail = findViewById(R.id.email);
        editTextPassword = findViewById(R.id.password);
        nameEditText = findViewById(R.id.regi_name);
        buttonReg = findViewById(R.id.btn_register);
        progressBar = findViewById(R.id.progressBar);

        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

        textView = findViewById(R.id.loginNow);

        textView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Login.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            }
        });

        buttonReg.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                String email, password;

                email = String.valueOf(editTextEmail.getText());
                password = String.valueOf(editTextPassword.getText());

                if (TextUtils.isEmpty(email)){
                    Toast.makeText(Register.this, "Enter Email | NO Email", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return;
                }

                if (TextUtils.isEmpty(password)){
                    Toast.makeText(Register.this, "Enter Password", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return;
                }

                mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
                        .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                                progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                                    Toast.makeText(Register.this, "Account successfully created",
                                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    // save the user details to DB
                                    FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
                                    FirebaseUser currentFirebaseUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser() ;
                                    DocumentReference df = fStore.collection("User").document(user.getUid());
                                    Map<String, Object>userInfo = new HashMap<>();
                                    userInfo.put("Name",nameEditText.getText().toString());
                                    userInfo.put("UserEmail",editTextEmail.getText().toString());
                                     // access level
                                    userInfo.put("isAdmin", "0");

                                    df.set(userInfo);

                                    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Login.class);
                                    startActivity(intent);
                                    finish();

                                } else {
                                    // If sign in fails, display a message to the user.
                                    Log.w(TAG, "createUserWithEmail:failure", task.getException());
                                    Toast.makeText(Register.this, "Authentication failed.",
                                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                }
                            }
                        });

            }
        });
    }
}
```

*activity_register.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="15dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    tools:context=".Register">

    <TextView
        android:text="@string/register"
        android:textSize="28sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:id="@+id/regi_name"
            android:hint="@string/name"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:id="@+id/email"
            android:hint="@string/email"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>


    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:id="@+id/password"
            android:hint="@string/password"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_register"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/btn_register"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/loginNow"
        android:text="@string/click_to_login"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: You never initialize `fStore`. See the question I linked to learn how to troubleshoot this error going forward, and the documentation on [initializing Firestore in your Android app](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quickstart#kotlin+ktx_1) to learn how to initialize a reference to Firestore.

Answer (score 1):

I do not see where "`fStore`" is set.  From the code you posted it looks like maybe you forgot to set it and then attempt to use it in the line `DocumentReference df = fStore.collection("User").document(user.getUid());`.

Comment: it's there, code line 39 **FirebaseFirestore fStore;**

Comment: That is where you declare it, but I do not see it's value being set anywhere.  In Java that means it will default to NULL.  I think you probably mean to set it to a reference to Firebase Firestore.  I don't recall the Java syntax for this, but in JavaScript you would make sure Firebase is initialized "firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);" and then get a reference to Firestore "firebase.firestore()".

Comment: It looks like in Java you could use the "com.google.firebase.cloud.FirestoreClient" class and then use "FirestoreClient.getFirestore()" to get the Firestore instance associated with the default Firebase app.